# Need to find anime with a half-demon protagonist and his demon-killing gang

Tags: saiyuki

The protagonist was a half demon man. He was wandering with his group (a black/dark blue haired man with glasses), and some other guy. They were killing demons.

As I remember, he used bullets that killed demons. I remember 2 episodes.

- In one of the episodes, he and his group arrived at a village. The villagers were working at the fields, and they didn't greet the strangers. As they passed the villagers, they found a big Japanese house. There was a woman in it, who sang every night. Later it was revealed that she was a demon, who extracted people's "bad memories", and kept them in oval spheres. The spheres had a vision of the person whose memory was extracted. Whomever she did this to became her slave. She was like a siren with her voice.
- In the other episode, there was a village in a forest. A famous restaurant/dumpling shop opened, but the owner, a young woman's cook was uneatable. It was revealed that she had the special ability to KILL DEMONS with her FOOD. She threw dumplings into the demons mouth to kill them, or just sprout her soup that will make the demons melt.

I don't remember the name of the anime, but it was old school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be [**Saiyuki**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saiyuki_(manga))

[image]

> Saiyuki is the story of four anti-heroes: the monk Genjyo Sanzo (or just "Sanzo"), the monkey king Son Goku, the half-demon Sha Gojyo, and the man who turned into a demon Cho Hakkai (formerly known as Cho Gonou). They have been dispatched by the Sanbutsushin (the Three Aspects of Buddha, who relay the orders of heaven) to travel to India to stop the possible resurrection of the Ox-Demon-King, Gyumaoh. Along the way they are beset by inept assassins, bad weather, and their own tragic personal pasts. Meanwhile, the villains, two unlikely confidants, Gyokumen Koushou (Gyumaoh's concubine, a demon) and a mad scientist, Dr. Nii Jianyi (a human), continue their attempts to restore the long-dead king. These experiments, a forbidden mixture of science and magic, spawn the "Minus Wave", infecting all of the demons in Shangri-La with madness, shattering the fragile peace that once existed between humans and demons.

In particular the episodes you are referring to are from the series **Saiyuki Reload**

- [**Episode 5:**](http://www.tv.com/shows/saiyuki-reload/slumbering-memories-401269/)

  > A peaceful demon, Suika, who cooks wonderful meals allows the Sanzo Party to stay at their village overnight. During the night, she sings and visits all of their dreams, extracting their painful memories from them and making them "happy." The next day, Sanzo and the others, except Goku, are all acting funny and lifeless. When confronted by Lirin on the road, Sanzo tosses the Maten Scripture at her when she demands it and goes back to Suika's village with Hakkai and Gojyo. Yaone tells Goku a story about a demon that extracts painful memories. Goku and the others head back to the village to try and free the others
- [**Episode 8:**](http://www.tv.com/shows/saiyuki-reload/tasty-cooking-401272/)

  > The Sanzo party meet a woman who cooks so terribly, people actually use her food as weapons against demons! Goku tries her food and gets sick, though. Hakkai realizes, however, that she really wants to be a good cook for her boyfriend, even though her horirble-tasting food makes for a handy weapon. Hakkai gives her cooking lessons, but when he tries her food, he passes out! Her boyfriend is horrified to hear they're eating her food, and Hakkai tries to explain that she wants to cook well. Her boyfriend decides he'll try her food for himself, as horrible as it may be. As she makes a dish, a demon attacks. She throws the soup on the demon and he disentrigrates. Her boyfriend tries her food, though, and finds it delicious. Sanzo decides that her food kills demons, similar to the way the banishing gun bullets kill them. As thanks for helping her, she gives them all a plate of meat buns, but Hakkai, Gojyo, and Goku don't want to eat them. On their way out, though, they run into a bunch of demons...